# Error while Accessing 2d array in Python 2.7

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, 2d

I'm beginner in python and i want to access each elemnt in a 2d matrix.
i'm using this code.

```
a=[]
for i in xrange(3):
     a.append([])
     for j in xrange(3):
        a[i].append(i+j)
print a
print a[0,2]
```

but while i'm executing the element at a[0,2] it's giving me an error.

```
[[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/--/--/1B.py", line 10, in <module>
    print a[0,2]
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple
```

can anyone help me out ? Any help would be aprreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do `a[0][2]`, not `a[0,2]`.

### Cause of the Error

The error you are getting is because Python doesn't recognise `0,2` as a valid index. This is not surprising - indices are supposed to be pure integers only, not `<integer>, <integer>`. The Python interpreter recognises these as two separate integers, but doesn't know what to do with them.

Instead, what you really want is to think about it this way:

- Doing `a[0]` gives you the *first* list in `a`.
- Doing `a[0][2]` now accesses the first list in `a`, and then accesses the second element in *that* list.

If you did `b = a[0]` and then called `b[2]`, you'd get exactly the same behaviour - because that is what's happening when you do `a[0][2]`. This is also the way how two-dimensional arrays are usually accessed in other languages as well, so it's good to know upfront how to work with them in this regard.

Comment: Thanx a lot @akshat-mahajan

Comment: @KrishnaKumar Mark as accepted answer if this helped you.

Comment: also i want to know one more thing , how do i count the occurence of an element in the same array, say for eg. i want to count the occurence of a[0][2], a.count(a[0][2]) is not working for me.

Comment: @KrishnaKumar You should ask this as a separate question, but it depends on what you mean by 'count the occurence'. If you want to count how many times the _value_ of `a[0][2]` appears in the entire 2D array, then you have to write a nested for loops to iterate over index and check every value - there is no way around it. If you only want to count how many times it occurs in the same _row_, then `a[0].count(a[0][2])` is what you're looking for.

Comment: Btw, upvoting is not the same as marking as accepted answer. There's a small tick mark below the vote counter - you have to press that.

Comment: thanx a lot. Ok i'll do it.